# How do I bind to a property on the DataContext without using a DependencyProperty?

Tags: silverlight

I know how to bind to a `DependencyProperty` and how to create my own `DependencyProperty`'s.  Is there a way to get the value from the `DataContext` of the control in its code behind using the binding system (i.e. not reflection)?  I'm considering a method of binding directly to the code behind rather than having to bind through the interface. I know that I could just create a DependencyProperty and bind to that, but I was just wondering if there was a way using a `BindingExpression` or something to forgo having to create a `DependencyProperty`.

I'm using Silverlight 4 with Expression Blend 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what you're looking for. could you please explain your problem more? maybe give some code snippets?

Comment: Why the "not reflection" restriction? You can bind to non-dependency properties, but you're specifically ruling that out for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only two ways you could do this are via reflection, or by creating a 'local' dependency property and binding that to your DataContext by some expression. There is no other 'magic' way!